# Terraform GCP Compute Engine startup script inline using a variable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-compute-engine, terraform-provider-gcp

I'll be needing to use a startup script

`metadata_startup_script = "filemage init --email <vaulue> --reset"`

But I'll have value as a terraform variable

`metadata_startup_script = "filemage init --email $var.email --reset"`

How can I do this without a template file so it's all inline instead?

Comment: Well, you can try, run `terraform validate` and `terraform plan`. :)

Comment: But anyway the second syntax will not work for sure without the curly brackets. :)